# Given thermal capability of a transformer, how to best estimate the voltage regulation?

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

I'm working with a system that has 3 2MVA transformers for which there is an existing estimate of the peak load and the power factor. The xfmrs appear to have a greater thermal capability than the rating (up to ~120% per xfrmr), and we're adding a shunt cap-bank ~1MVA to improve the voltage regulation.

I'm trying to nail down what the MVA rating of the cap bank is going to be and whether to increase or lower the rating to decrease the load to the thermal capability of the xfmrs. However, I don't know how to estimate the quantity of voltage regulation given the thermal capability. I'm assuming this is due to I^2 R losses in the transformers.

Much appreciated.

Comment: You say you are adding a shunt cap bank to improve regulation but, "this does not compute". Have you any idea what you are doing or why you are doing it? Also note that voltage regulation of a transformer depends on leakage components in the windings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was making this too difficult. ~120% thermal capability of the transformers means they can each have 120% of their KVA rating.

Hence the bank will need about 647 KVAR of additional caps.

Comment: I'm not a power engineer, but this sounds wrong.

Comment: Understandable, the problem is that the terminology is confusing. This is a simple power-triangle problem in disguise. The solution method is from a book on power systems, and that is the correct additional rating needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the transformers can be operated at 120% of their base rating, that probably only applies to operating conditions that are different from the base conditions. Alternate ratings are often stated for operation with cooling fans. Alternate ratings might also be published for operation below rated ambient temperature or below rated site altitude. If any of those conditions apply, that would not improve transformer regulation unless the actual operating KVA is found to be less than the rated KVA by virtue of the actual operating conditions. That would mean that the temperature rise would be lower than rated and the winding resistance would be lower than rated as a result.

There is not enough information in the question to determine what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

With capacitor bank you can do a power factor correction.
S^2 = P^2 + Q^2
When properly tuned, the cap bank eliminates the reactive power component, thus the current in xfmr is reduced  by this amount, but the power rating remains the same. You should look at the reactive power when switching caps.